# How do I get the position of the UIImageView in my UIScrollView and only allow it to be panned?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

To me it seems that when I embed a `UIImageView` in a `UIScrollView` it's very difficult to get information on the `UIImageView` and be able to manipulate it.

I have a fullscreen `UIScrollView` that allows to zoom in the `UIImageView` to the full size of the screen.

But if I want to be able to "throw" the `UIImageView` in the scroll view off the screen (similar to Tweetbot or Facebook) I'm not able to add the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the image view, I have to add it to the scroll view.

Annoyingly, this means the user can start the pan from anywhere within the full screen scroll view, not just on the image. **Is it possible to make it so only the image can be panned, not the full scroll view?**

Hand in hand with this is the fact that I can't seem to get the frame of the image in the scrollview. If I ask for the scrollview's frame as it's panned, I obviously get the full scrollview, not just the image inside it, which does not accurately show where the image is. On the flip side, if I try to get the frame of the image it never changes, as it's moving relative to the scroll view. **How do I get the location the image is at currently?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it possible to make it so only the image can be panned, not the full scroll view?**

Implement `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` in your gesture recogniser's delegate, then test that `UITouch`'s position against that of your image view.

So, probably something like:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:scrollView];
return CGRectContainsPoint(imageView.frame, touchLocation);
```

**How do I get the location the image is at currently?**

According to which coordinate space? Assuming you mean relative to a view controller's top-level view, use [`[viewController.view convertRect:imageView.frame fromView:scrollView]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertRect%3afromView%3a).

Scroll views scroll their content by changing their `bounds`. They don't change anything on the included views. `UIView -convertRect:fromView` and the others consolidate all the logic for mapping from the internal coordinate space of one view to another, adjusting for transforms and internal scrolling and everything.